# An efficient way to check index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I have an n x n 2D array, and need to connect random points to four neighbors (sorry I added the picture, but it seems one has to click on the link for the image to show).

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPDCS.jpg)

I would like to use code like this:

```
connect(p, p - n);
connect(p, p + n);
connect(p, p - 1);
connect(p, p + 1);
```

The problem I am having now is the index out of bounds for the ones on the edge. Originally I created array of size (n + 2) * (n + 2) to resolve the issue. That preserved the simplicity of the code, however I failed the storage requirement for the assignment. The array has to be n * n.

I researched and revised my algorithm

```
connect(grid[i][j], grid[Math.max(0, i-1)][j]);
connect(grid[i][j], grid[Math.min(n - 1, i+1)][j]);
connect(grid[i][j], grid[i][Math.max(0, j-1)]);
connect(grid[i][j], grid[i][Math.min(n - 1, j+1)]);
```

Right now, it would connect the point to itself it is out of bounds.My question is -- is there a better/cleaner way to check if indices out of bounds? Thank you all.

Comment: Do you intend to land on the opposite side of the grid if you are out of bounds or do you want to ignore those points completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally goes for:

```
connect(grid, i, j, i - 1, j);
```

And have `connect` does this:

```
void connect(Point[][] grid, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  if (x2 < 0 || y2 < 0  || 
      x2 >= grid.length || y2 >= grid.length) { // see note
    return; // nothing to do out of bounds
  }
  connect(grid[x1][y1], grid[x2][y2]);  
}
```

It fully assumes that your grid is a matrix of N*N.

You could also don't care about checking:

```
void connect(Point[][] grid, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  try {
    connect(grid[x1][y1], grid[x2][y2]);  
  } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException e) {
    // nasty
  }
}
```

I do think it is nasty because catching tend to cost more than checking - even if the check is done twice.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the connect method

```java
// p1 is valid, check p2
xxx  connectWrapper(xxx p1, xxx p2, int n){
    // check first
    if(p2.x < 0 || p2.y < 0 || p2.x > n || p2.y > n) return;
    connect(p1, p2);
}
```

So you can use this connectWrapper to replace the connect method as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can always loop through the neighbors.  I often do it like this:

```
for (int ni=0; ni<4; ++ni) {
    // starting at (x,y-1), bit 0 of ni means go SE, and bit 1 means go SW
    int nx = x + (ni&1) - (ni>>1);
    int ny = y - 1 + (ni&1) + (ni>>1);
    if (nx >= 0 && ny >= 0 && nx < width && ny < height) {
        connect(x,y,nx,ny);
    }
}
```

When I'm picky about going through the neighbors in a specific order:

```
for (int dir=0x12011021; dir!=0; dir>>=8) {
    int nx = x - 1 + ((dir>>4)&3);
    int ny = y - 1 + (dir&3);
    if (nx >= 0 && ny >= 0 && nx < width && ny < height) {
        connect(x,y,nx,ny);
    }
}
```